# Override @RequestMapping method using inheritance

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, inheritance

In my Java Spring MVC 4 project, I have an AbstractRESTController with an update method:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value="/{id}",
        method=RequestMethod.PUT,
        consumes={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}
)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<T> update(@PathVariable ID id, 
    @RequestParam String token, @RequestBody T json) {
        [do fancy stuff]
}
```

and an extending class, let's call it `MyController`. Usually I want to use the method from the abstract class, but in `MyController` I have a special case (yay!), so I need to do further work.

My idea was to just override the `@RequestMapping` in the child class, do my `additional fancy stuff` and afterwards call the super class' update method from the `MyController.update` method. But this does not work, because I get an ambiguous mapping error during compilation.

Is there a way to make Spring override the parent class request mapping? I would like to avoid splitting the routes.

Comment: As a route is intended to point at a specific method, I don't think you're going to be able to do it quite that way. Perhaps if you were to do your processing of the request in a separate method and override that method in those child classes which need their own implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have noticed you can't do this because the ambiguous mapping.

If you want execute some additional code, you can use something like [hook methods](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HookMethod). So, define in your `AbstractRESTController` an empty method like this:

```
protected void doFancyStuff() {

}
```

Obs.: the empty method is a better choice here, and not an `abstract` one, to avoid the need to implement even with empty method body in all concrete controller.

Change the update method to call the hook method:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value="/{id}",
        method=RequestMethod.PUT,
        consumes={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}
)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<T> update(@PathVariable ID id, 
    @RequestParam String token, @RequestBody T json) {
        doFancyStuff();
}
```

And in `MyController` you will override and implement `doFancyStuff` method.

Comment: I really like this idea, and it works for me. I do not think that this is 100% elegant but maybe still the best solution in this case.

Comment: @dexBerlin I agree with you, this is not 100% elegant. I like to use methods such as `doBeforeUpdate`, `doAfterUpdate`, etc. To abstract common and specific behaviors.

Comment: i have a AbstractCtrl that calls my services rest layer. this solution fits perfect.